# Реализация объединения таблиц many-to-many в asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, codefirst

Есть таблица Menu, который содержит в себе Роли, для которых это меню может показываться

```
public class Menu : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Priority { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<MenuRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Так же есть таблица Role, расширяющий основную модель роли добавляя туда список Menu

```
public class Role : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<MenuRole> Menu { get; set; }
}
```

И есть объединяющая таблица

```
public class MenuRole
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }

    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Я помню, что раньше в ЕF можно было не создавать доп. таблицу, она автоматически формировалась при миграции в БД, сейчас же она нужна, и по этому добавляются лишние переходы при получении Ролей:

```
Menu.Roles.Select(x=> x.Role...)
```

Можно ли как ни будь смапить или сформировать данные пришедшие с БД сразу в список IEnumerable < Role > и пропускать эту таблицу из выборки?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете Entity Framework Core, то такая возможность появилась в 5 версии. На данный момент доступен второй релиз кандидат и по заверения Microsoft он готов для использования на боевой среде. Достаточно будет описать модель следующим образом:

```
public class Menu : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Priority { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Menu> Menu { get; set; }
}
```

Обновите ваши nugget пакеты EF Core до версии "5.0.0-rc.*", для более ранних версии EF Core, необходимо создавать объединяющую сущность модели.

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many).